# Submiting a form with Ajax by using FormData on Firefox and IE10+

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a normal form that i submit with ajax. The Ajax code is next:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: new FormData( this ),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if(response == 1) {
        // do something
      } else {
        // do something else
      }
   }
});
```

It works perfect in Google Chrome and Safari. But when i tested on IE10+ ( i know that FormData is not working below ie10) and Firefox is not working, is not submiting the Post info to the php file. What should be the cause ?

Comment: Why not use `$(this).serialize()`? Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: thank you, i watched the request and found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used for the input type submit button a value that whould capture the POST on the php side. The problem is that on Firefox or IE10+ the PostData doesn`t send the input type submit name. So i made a hidden input that uses the same name like the input type submit, and now it works. Very strange issue.

THIS DOESNT SUBMIT WITH FormData

```
<input type="submit" name="project-form" value="SUBMIT FORM">
```

THIS DOES SUBMIT

```
<input type="hidden" name="project-form" value="true">
```