# AJAX formdata POST submit working in IE9/Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some AJAX script that submits a form and then updates the web page.

My Code:

HTML:

```
<form action='jobs.php' method='post' name='editUpdate' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form-add">
    <hr />
    <textarea name='description'  id="title" class="text1" placeholder="Add Update" cols='100' rows='5'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name='action' id="submit" value="Save Update"></input>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
$('#form-add').submit(function(e){
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var prependbdDiv = $('#prependbody');

    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        dataType: "json",
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.success == "1"){
                prependbdDiv.prepend("<tr><td>"+response.datetime+"</td><td>"+response.updatedesc+"</td></tr>");
               $('#title').val('');
               $("#form-add").fadeToggle();
            }
        },
        error: function(response) 
        {
            alert("ERROR");
        },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}); 
</script>
```

This seems to have resolved my issue:
[Submiting a form with Ajax by using FormData on Firefox and IE10+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431021/submiting-a-form-with-ajax-by-using-formdata-on-firefox-and-ie10)

I am curious why this is the case or is it bad programming on my behalf?
Also when using FireBug the post data does not appear similar to that of the post data from a standard HTML form. IE, with the ajax post using `formdata` FireBug lists no "Parts" section under the POST details.

Thanks for your help!